# How to get a derived value from a class that is not a class attribute?

Tags: python

I am trying to define a class to handle sheet metal.  Sheet metal has a thickness but it also has a gauge association that we humans use to reference the material.  I am trying to have a function that will provide the gauge based on the thickness but I can't get it to work.  The result I get when I run my code is `<bound method Sheet.get_gauge of ST - 0.05 X 120 X 48>`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from msilib.schema import Property


@dataclass
class Sheet:
    def __init__(self, material_type: str, thickness: float, X_dim: int, Y_dim: int):
        # Run validations to received arguments
        assert 0.03 <= thickness <= 2.0, f"Sheet {thickness} must be greater than or equal to 0.03 and less than or equal to 2.0"
        assert material_type == 'ST' or 'SS' or 'AL', f"Material type can only be ST, SS or AL"

        # Assign to self object
        self.material_type = material_type
        self.thickness = thickness
        self.X_dim = X_dim
        self.Y_dim = Y_dim

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.material_type} - {self.thickness} X {self.X_dim} X {self.Y_dim}"

    # Each material type's thickness has a different Guage scale

    def get_gauge(self):
        st_sht_thk = ['.04', '.05', '.06', '.078', '.105', '.12', '.135', '.171', '.179', '.188',
                      '.25', '.31', '.38', '.5', '.63', '.75', '.88', '1.0', '1.25', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5']
        stl_ga = ['20ga', '18ga', '16ga', '14ga', '12ga', '11ga', '10ga', '8ga', '7ga', '3/16th', '1/4in',
                  '5/16th', '3/8th', '1/2in', '5/8th', '3/4in', '7/8th', '1in', '1.25in', '1.5in', '2.0in', '2.5']
        if self.material_type == 'ST':
            pos = st_sht_thk.index(self.thickness)
            ga = stl_ga[pos]
        print(ga)


sheet2 = Sheet('ST', .05, 120, 48)
print(sheet2.get_gauge)
```

Comment: For one thing, don't use the `dataclass` decorator if you aren't going to use it as a dataclass. That means, don't override `__init__` and do set class attributes with type annotations. This code is opposite of that. Next, seems like you need a lookup table with nearest neighbor selection. A dictionary makes a great lookup table. However, the error you're getting is because `get_gauge` is a function, and you are not calling it with `()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I re wrote it as a proper data class.  And I called the function correctly and it works.  I will also convert the two lists into a dictionary and get the value that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the function `sheet2.get_gauge`, but printing its reference. In order to execute it you need to call it with brackets:

```
print(sheet2.get_gauge())
```